# Why does Oraoop 1.6 wait 1.5 minutes before allocating memory chunks?

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, sqoop, hortonworks-data-platform

Using SQOOP 1.4.4 and Oraoop 1.6 we always have a 1.5+ minute wait, regardless of the row/column count of the table. Using `--verbose` doesn't reveal any more info. The `SQOOP` command is not overriding any -D variable.

Here is the output of the command:

```
15/01/14 02:08:13 INFO oraoop.OracleConnectionFactory: Initializing Oracle session with SQL : alter session set tracefile_identifier=oraoop
15/01/14 02:09:48 INFO oraoop.OraOopDataDrivenDBInputFormat: The table being imported by sqoop has 320 blocks that have been divided into 5 chunks which will be processed in 5 splits. The chunks will be allocated to the splits using the method : ROUNDROBIN
```

We found that this query takes up most or all of that time:

```
 SELECT   data_object_id, file_id, relative_fno, file_batch,
         MIN (start_block_id) start_block_id, MAX (end_block_id) end_block_id,
         SUM (blocks) blocks
    FROM (SELECT o.data_object_id, e.file_id, e.relative_fno,
                 e.block_id start_block_id,
                 e.block_id + e.blocks - 1 end_block_id, e.blocks,
                 CEIL
                    (  SUM (e.blocks) OVER (PARTITION BY o.data_object_id, e.file_id ORDER BY e.block_id ASC)
                     / (  SUM (e.blocks) OVER (PARTITION BY o.data_object_id, e.file_id)
                        / :numchunks
                       )
                    ) file_batch
            FROM dba_extents e, dba_objects o, dba_tab_subpartitions tsp
           WHERE o.owner = :owner
             AND o.object_name = :object_name
             AND e.owner = :owner
             AND e.segment_name = :object_name
             AND o.owner = e.owner
             AND o.object_name = e.segment_name
             AND (   o.subobject_name = e.partition_name
                  OR (o.subobject_name IS NULL AND e.partition_name IS NULL)
                 )
             AND o.owner = tsp.table_owner(+)
             AND o.object_name = tsp.table_name(+)
             AND o.subobject_name = tsp.subpartition_name(+))
GROUP BY data_object_id, file_id, relative_fno, file_batch
ORDER BY data_object_id, file_id, relative_fno, file_batch
```

Following is the plan:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                      | Name                      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                               |                           |       |       |  2383 (100)|          |
|   1 |  SORT GROUP BY                                 |                           |     3 |   246 |  2383   (2)| 00:00:34 |
|   2 |   VIEW                                         |                           |     3 |   246 |  2382   (2)| 00:00:34 |
|   3 |    WINDOW SORT                                 |                           |     3 |   804 |  2382   (2)| 00:00:34 |
|*  4 |     FILTER                                     |                           |       |       |            |          |
|*  5 |      HASH JOIN                                 |                           |     3 |   804 |  2381   (2)| 00:00:34 |
|*  6 |       HASH JOIN OUTER                          |                           |     2 |   298 |    53   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|   7 |        VIEW                                    | DBA_OBJECTS               |     2 |   226 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   8 |         UNION-ALL                              |                           |       |       |            |          |
|*  9 |          FILTER                                |                           |       |       |            |          |
|* 10 |           FILTER                               |                           |       |       |            |          |
|  11 |            NESTED LOOPS                        |                           |     1 |    86 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  12 |             NESTED LOOPS                       |                           |     1 |    64 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  13 |              TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID       | USER$                     |     1 |    15 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 14 |               INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                | I_USER1                   |     1 |       |     0   (0)|          |
|* 15 |              TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID       | OBJ$                      |     1 |    49 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 16 |               INDEX RANGE SCAN                 | I_OBJ5                    |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 17 |             INDEX RANGE SCAN                   | I_USER2                   |     1 |    22 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  18 |           NESTED LOOPS                         |                           |     1 |    30 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 19 |            INDEX SKIP SCAN                     | I_USER2                   |     1 |    20 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 20 |            INDEX RANGE SCAN                    | I_OBJ4                    |     1 |    10 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 21 |          FILTER                                |                           |       |       |            |          |
|  22 |           NESTED LOOPS                         |                           |     1 |    45 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  23 |            TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID         | USER$                     |     1 |    15 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 24 |             INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                  | I_USER1                   |     1 |       |     0   (0)|          |
|* 25 |            INDEX RANGE SCAN                    | I_LINK1                   |     1 |    30 |     0   (0)|          |
|  26 |        VIEW                                    | DBA_TAB_SUBPARTITIONS     |     9 |   324 |    47   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|* 27 |         FILTER                                 |                           |       |       |            |          |
|  28 |          NESTED LOOPS OUTER                    |                           |     9 |  1215 |    47   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|  29 |           NESTED LOOPS                         |                           |     8 |   984 |    39   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|  30 |            NESTED LOOPS                        |                           |     8 |   912 |    31   (4)| 00:00:01 |
|  31 |             NESTED LOOPS                       |                           |     8 |   888 |    23   (5)| 00:00:01 |
|  32 |              NESTED LOOPS OUTER                |                           |     8 |   776 |     7  (15)| 00:00:01 |
|* 33 |               HASH JOIN                        |                           |     8 |   728 |     7  (15)| 00:00:01 |
|  34 |                NESTED LOOPS                    |                           |       |       |            |          |
|  35 |                 NESTED LOOPS                   |                           |     8 |   632 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  36 |                  NESTED LOOPS                  |                           |     1 |    54 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  37 |                   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | USER$                     |     1 |    15 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 38 |                    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN           | I_USER1                   |     1 |       |     0   (0)|          |
|* 39 |                   INDEX RANGE SCAN             | I_OBJ2                    |     1 |    39 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 40 |                  INDEX RANGE SCAN              | I_TABSUBPART_POBJSUBPART$ |    11 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  41 |                 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID    | TABSUBPART$               |    11 |   275 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  42 |                TABLE ACCESS FULL               | TABCOMPART$               |    61 |   732 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 43 |               INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                | I_DEFERRED_STG1           |     1 |     6 |     0   (0)|          |
|* 44 |              TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID       | OBJ$                      |     1 |    14 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 45 |               INDEX RANGE SCAN                 | I_OBJ1                    |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  46 |             TABLE ACCESS CLUSTER               | TS$                       |     1 |     3 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 47 |              INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                 | I_TS#                     |     1 |       |     0   (0)|          |
|* 48 |            TABLE ACCESS CLUSTER                | TAB$                      |     1 |     9 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 49 |             INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                  | I_OBJ#                    |     1 |       |     0   (0)|          |
|  50 |           TABLE ACCESS CLUSTER                 | SEG$                      |     1 |    12 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 51 |            INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                   | I_FILE#_BLOCK#            |     1 |       |     0   (0)|          |
|  52 |       VIEW                                     | DBA_EXTENTS               |   140 | 16660 |  2328   (2)| 00:00:33 |
|  53 |        UNION-ALL                               |                           |       |       |            |          |
|* 54 |         FILTER                                 |                           |       |       |            |          |
|  55 |          NESTED LOOPS                          |                           |     1 |   177 |   896   (0)| 00:00:13 |
|  56 |           NESTED LOOPS                         |                           |     1 |    89 |    28   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  57 |            TABLE ACCESS FULL                   | UET$                      |     1 |    78 |    28   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  58 |            TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID         | FILE$                     |     1 |    11 |     0   (0)|          |
|* 59 |             INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                  | I_FILE2                   |     1 |       |     0   (0)|          |
|  60 |           VIEW                                 | SYS_DBA_SEGS              |     1 |    88 |   868   (0)| 00:00:13 |
|  61 |            UNION ALL PUSHED PREDICATE          |                           |       |       |            |          |
|* 62 |             FILTER                             |                           |       |       |            |          |
|  63 |              NESTED LOOPS                      |                           |     1 |    99 |   860   (0)| 00:00:13 |
|* 64 |               FILTER                           |                           |       |       |            |          |
|  65 |                NESTED LOOPS OUTER              |                           |     1 |    84 |   844   (0)| 00:00:12 |
|  66 |                 MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN           |                           |     1 |    69 |   843   (0)| 00:00:12 |
|  67 |                  NESTED LOOPS                  |                           |     1 |    31 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  68 |                   NESTED LOOPS                 |                           |     1 |    10 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 69 |                    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN           | I_FILE2                   |     1 |     7 |     0   (0)|          |
|  70 |                    TABLE ACCESS CLUSTER        | TS$                       |     1 |     3 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 71 |                     INDEX UNIQUE SCAN          | I_TS#                     |     1 |       |     0   (0)|          |
|* 72 |                   TABLE ACCESS CLUSTER         | SEG$                      |     1 |    21 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 73 |                    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN           | I_FILE#_BLOCK#            |     1 |       |     0   (0)|          |
|  74 |                  BUFFER SORT                   |                           |     3 |   114 |   842   (0)| 00:00:12 |
|* 75 |                   INDEX SKIP SCAN              | I_OBJ5                    |     3 |   114 |   841   (0)| 00:00:12 |
|  76 |                 TABLE ACCESS CLUSTER           | USER$                     |     1 |    15 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 77 |                  INDEX UNIQUE SCAN             | I_USER#                   |     1 |       |     0   (0)|          |
|* 78 |               VIEW                             | SYS_OBJECTS               |     3 |    45 |    16   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  79 |                UNION ALL PUSHED PREDICATE      |                           |       |       |            |          |
|* 80 |                 TABLE ACCESS CLUSTER           | TAB$                      |     1 |    25 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 81 |                  INDEX UNIQUE SCAN             | I_OBJ#                    |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 82 |                 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID    | TABPART$                  |     1 |    18 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 83 |                  INDEX UNIQUE SCAN             | I_TABPART_OBJ$            |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 84 |                 TABLE ACCESS CLUSTER           | CLU$                      |     1 |    14 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 85 |                  INDEX UNIQUE SCAN             | I_OBJ#                    |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 86 |                 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID    | IND$                      |     1 |    21 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 87 |                  INDEX UNIQUE SCAN             | I_IND1                    |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 88 |                 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID    | INDPART$                  |     1 |    18 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 89 |                  INDEX UNIQUE SCAN             | I_INDPART_OBJ$            |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 90 |                 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID    | LOB$                      |     1 |    20 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 91 |                  INDEX UNIQUE SCAN             | I_LOB2                    |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 92 |                 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID    | TABSUBPART$               |     1 |    19 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 93 |                  INDEX UNIQUE SCAN             | I_TABSUBPART$_OBJ$        |     1 |       |     0   (0)|          |
|* 94 |                 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID    | INDSUBPART$               |     1 |    19 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 95 |                  INDEX UNIQUE SCAN             | I_INDSUBPART_OBJ$         |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 96 |                 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID    | LOBFRAG$                  |     1 |    16 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 97 |                  INDEX UNIQUE SCAN             | I_LOBFRAG$_FRAGOBJ$       |     1 |       |     0   (0)|          |
|* 98 |             FILTER                             |                           |       |       |            |          |
|* 99 |              FILTER                            |                           |       |       |            |          |
| 100 |               NESTED LOOPS OUTER               |                           |     1 |    77 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
| 101 |                NESTED LOOPS                    |                           |     1 |    62 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
| 102 |                 NESTED LOOPS                   |                           |     1 |    37 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
| 103 |                  NESTED LOOPS                  |                           |     1 |    10 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*104 |                   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN            | I_FILE2                   |     1 |     7 |     0   (0)|          |
| 105 |                   TABLE ACCESS CLUSTER         | TS$                       |     1 |     3 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*106 |                    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN           | I_TS#                     |     1 |       |     0   (0)|          |
|*107 |                  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   | UNDO$                     |     1 |    27 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*108 |                   INDEX RANGE SCAN             | I_UNDO2                   |     1 |       |     0   (0)|          |
|*109 |                 TABLE ACCESS CLUSTER           | SEG$                      |     1 |    25 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*110 |                  INDEX UNIQUE SCAN             | I_FILE#_BLOCK#            |     1 |       |     0   (0)|          |
| 111 |                TABLE ACCESS CLUSTER            | USER$                     |     1 |    15 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*112 |                 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN              | I_USER#                   |     1 |       |     0   (0)|          |
|*113 |             FILTER                             |                           |       |       |            |          |
|*114 |              FILTER                            |                           |       |       |            |          |
| 115 |               NESTED LOOPS OUTER               |                           |     1 |    54 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
| 116 |                NESTED LOOPS                    |                           |     1 |    39 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
| 117 |                 NESTED LOOPS                   |                           |     1 |    14 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
| 118 |                  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   | FILE$                     |     1 |    11 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*119 |                   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN            | I_FILE2                   |     1 |       |     0   (0)|          |
| 120 |                  TABLE ACCESS CLUSTER          | TS$                       |     1 |     3 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*121 |                   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN            | I_TS#                     |     1 |       |     0   (0)|          |
|*122 |                 TABLE ACCESS CLUSTER           | SEG$                      |     1 |    25 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*123 |                  INDEX UNIQUE SCAN             | I_FILE#_BLOCK#            |     1 |       |     0   (0)|          |
| 124 |                TABLE ACCESS CLUSTER            | USER$                     |     1 |    15 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*125 |                 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN              | I_USER#                   |     1 |       |     0   (0)|          |
|*126 |         FILTER                                 |                           |       |       |            |          |
|*127 |          HASH JOIN                             |                           |   139 | 24603 |  1431   (2)| 00:00:21 |
|*128 |           HASH JOIN                            |                           |   238 | 23562 |  1406   (1)| 00:00:20 |
| 129 |            VIEW                                | SYS_DBA_SEGS              |    37 |  3256 |  1403   (0)| 00:00:20 |
| 130 |             UNION-ALL                          |                           |       |       |            |          |
|*131 |              FILTER                            |                           |       |       |            |          |
| 132 |               NESTED LOOPS                     |                           |    35 |  3465 |  1015   (1)| 00:00:15 |
| 133 |                NESTED LOOPS                    |                           |    35 |  3360 |   979   (0)| 00:00:14 |
| 134 |                 NESTED LOOPS                   |                           |    35 |  3115 |   979   (0)| 00:00:14 |
| 135 |                  NESTED LOOPS                  |                           |   119 |  8092 |   860   (0)| 00:00:13 |
|*136 |                   FILTER                       |                           |       |       |            |          |
| 137 |                    NESTED LOOPS OUTER          |                           |     1 |    53 |   844   (0)| 00:00:12 |
|*138 |                     INDEX SKIP SCAN            | I_OBJ5                    |     3 |   114 |   841   (0)| 00:00:12 |
| 139 |                     TABLE ACCESS CLUSTER       | USER$                     |     1 |    15 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*140 |                      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | I_USER#                   |     1 |       |     0   (0)|          |
|*141 |                   VIEW                         | SYS_OBJECTS               |     3 |    45 |    16   (0)| 00:00:01 |
| 142 |                    UNION ALL PUSHED PREDICATE  |                           |       |       |            |          |
|*143 |                     TABLE ACCESS CLUSTER       | TAB$                      |     1 |    25 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*144 |                      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | I_OBJ#                    |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
| 145 |                     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TABPART$                  |     1 |    18 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*146 |                      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | I_TABPART_OBJ$            |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
| 147 |                     TABLE ACCESS CLUSTER       | CLU$                      |     1 |    14 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*148 |                      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | I_OBJ#                    |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*149 |                     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| IND$                      |     1 |    21 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*150 |                      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | I_IND1                    |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
| 151 |                     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| INDPART$                  |     1 |    18 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*152 |                      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | I_INDPART_OBJ$            |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*153 |                     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| LOB$                      |     1 |    20 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*154 |                      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | I_LOB2                    |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
| 155 |                     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TABSUBPART$               |     1 |    19 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*156 |                      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | I_TABSUBPART$_OBJ$        |     1 |       |     0   (0)|          |
| 157 |                     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| INDSUBPART$               |     1 |    19 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*158 |                      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | I_INDSUBPART_OBJ$         |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
| 159 |                     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| LOBFRAG$                  |     1 |    16 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*160 |                      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | I_LOBFRAG$_FRAGOBJ$       |     1 |       |     0   (0)|          |
|*161 |                  TABLE ACCESS CLUSTER          | SEG$                      |     1 |    21 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*162 |                   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN            | I_FILE#_BLOCK#            |     1 |       |     0   (0)|          |
|*163 |                 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN              | I_FILE2                   |     1 |     7 |     0   (0)|          |
| 164 |                TABLE ACCESS CLUSTER            | TS$                       |     1 |     3 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*165 |                 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN              | I_TS#                     |     1 |       |     0   (0)|          |
|*166 |              FILTER                            |                           |       |       |            |          |
|*167 |               FILTER                           |                           |       |       |            |          |
| 168 |                NESTED LOOPS OUTER              |                           |     1 |    77 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
| 169 |                 NESTED LOOPS                   |                           |     1 |    62 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
| 170 |                  NESTED LOOPS                  |                           |     1 |    59 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
| 171 |                   NESTED LOOPS                 |                           |     1 |    34 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*172 |                    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | UNDO$                     |     1 |    27 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*173 |                     INDEX RANGE SCAN           | I_UNDO2                   |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*174 |                    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN           | I_FILE2                   |     1 |     7 |     0   (0)|          |
|*175 |                   TABLE ACCESS CLUSTER         | SEG$                      |     1 |    25 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*176 |                    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN           | I_FILE#_BLOCK#            |     1 |       |     0   (0)|          |
| 177 |                  TABLE ACCESS CLUSTER          | TS$                       |     1 |     3 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*178 |                   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN            | I_TS#                     |     1 |       |     0   (0)|          |
| 179 |                 TABLE ACCESS CLUSTER           | USER$                     |     1 |    15 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*180 |                  INDEX UNIQUE SCAN             | I_USER#                   |     1 |       |     0   (0)|          |
|*181 |              FILTER                            |                           |       |       |            |          |
|*182 |               FILTER                           |                           |       |       |            |          |
| 183 |                NESTED LOOPS OUTER              |                           |     1 |    54 |   384   (0)| 00:00:06 |
| 184 |                 NESTED LOOPS                   |                           |     1 |    39 |   383   (0)| 00:00:06 |
| 185 |                  NESTED LOOPS                  |                           |     1 |    36 |   382   (0)| 00:00:06 |
| 186 |                   TABLE ACCESS FULL            | FILE$                     |   290 |  3190 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*187 |                   TABLE ACCESS CLUSTER         | SEG$                      |     1 |    25 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*188 |                    INDEX RANGE SCAN            | I_FILE#_BLOCK#            |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
| 189 |                  TABLE ACCESS CLUSTER          | TS$                       |     1 |     3 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*190 |                   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN            | I_TS#                     |     1 |       |     0   (0)|          |
| 191 |                 TABLE ACCESS CLUSTER           | USER$                     |     1 |    15 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*192 |                  INDEX UNIQUE SCAN             | I_USER#                   |     1 |       |     0   (0)|          |
| 193 |            TABLE ACCESS FULL                   | FILE$                     |   290 |  3190 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
| 194 |           FIXED TABLE FULL                     | X$KTFBUE                  |   100K|  7617K|    24 (100)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is there a way to tune or override this query? Are there any other ways to increase the speed of this command?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have up-to-date optimizer statistics for the relevant tables.  Having many "Rows = 1" in the explain plan is often a sign of a bad plan.  Run these two statements to gather statistics:

```
begin
    dbms_stats.gather_dictionary_stats;
    dbms_stats.gather_fixed_objects_stats;
end;
/
```

If that fixes things, work with a DBA to ensure that at least `gather_dictionary_stats` is run periodically (as it should be by default).

---

If possible it might help to modify SQOOP to remove these redundant predicates:

```
AND o.owner = e.owner
AND o.object_name = e.segment_name
```

On my database, removing those two conditions significantly changed the plan.

---

If statistics don't help, and you can't modify the query, try using the SQL Tuning Advisor to recommend ways to fix the plan.

```
declare
    v_task_name varchar2(30);
begin
    v_task_name := dbms_sqltune.create_tuning_task(sql_id => 'f9nqqh167x884');
    dbms_sqltune.execute_tuning_task(task_name=> v_task_name);
    dbms_output.put_line('Task Name: '||v_task_name);
end;
/

select dbms_sqltune.report_tuning_task('TASK_609') from dual;
```

On my system it recommended creating a profile.  A profile provides lots of helpful information to the optimizer, things like, "this join really returns 200% more rows than estimated".

```
...

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FINDINGS SECTION (1 finding)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

1- SQL Profile Finding (see explain plans section below)
--------------------------------------------------------
  A potentially better execution plan was found for this statement.

  Recommendation (estimated benefit: 84.03%)
  ------------------------------------------
  - Consider accepting the recommended SQL profile.
    execute dbms_sqltune.accept_sql_profile(task_name => 'TASK_609',
            task_owner => 'JHELLER', replace => TRUE);

...
```

Comment: I am not aware of a way to modify the query without getting a patch - can someone correct me if i am mistaken? Also, it already uses bind variables.

Comment: Did gathering statistics help any?  You'll definitely want to try that first before you start messing with execution plans.  Also, if it uses bind variables can you post that in the plan?  Does it use something like `:owner` instead of `'FOO'`?